# Which Elements Need For a Simple Video Upload and play Script

Tags: php, mysql

hii i just need very simple video upload script like which don't have much option
just want to provide my users Video hosting that they can upload their Videos and embed that video in their page or can watch that on my site 
like http://www.vidpe.com/
or if u want to see big example daily-motion but i need just little script people can upload their videos and watch those videos 
thanks
or if i want to make my own script in php + mysql which source can be best for me for helping in this if already available script is here please provide me link 
just simple script not like phpmotion.com

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site for programming questions, not software recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this upland

http://www.uploadify.com/

you can restrict the extension in the same and it works in back end so not tolerate to end user

Thanks

Comment: Thanks But i am looking for only Video Upload Script Which also give the option of watching that video or people can embed that in their website

Answer (score 1):

This is also nice http://www.videoswiper.com/

Also http://www.uploadify.com/ is awesome , free and easy to integrate with many functionality.

Comment: i don't want to use any API i want to use my own server that people can upload their script using my script and they can watch on my site also embed that if i give them option that all what i want

Comment: Than you have to create your own custom php script to upload videos and for that have a look on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. its basic php file upload script. furthermore , for additional functionality, create your own code.

Comment: thanks but there must me some free uploaded script through using that i can easily get idea and customize that for my own use

Comment: Good luck , and share it with us if you find.